# Semantic UI build not overwriting variables with site global variables

Tags: build, gulp, global-variables, semantic-ui

I'm getting a strange problem with Semantic UI and I have no idea from where it's coming from.

I have set only the `@primaryColor` in the `site.variables` which is at `src/site/globals` folder but every time I run the Gulp `build` task from Semantic UI, it fills the `dist` folder with the standard Semantic files. It completely ignores the global variables I have set in my `site` folder.

Any ideas from where this problem could be coming?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Fabio.

Comment: Anybody? Any ideas?